# Bokeh Python: Server connection error

Tags: python, json, bokeh

When running the **animated** code found in (examples/plotting/server/animated.py), I get the error:

IOError: Cannot push session document because we failed to connect to the server (to start the server, try the 'bokeh serve' command)

I have read that removing **session = push_session(curdoc())** will resolve the issue as users hosting from localhosts do not need that line, however it is not clear what to replace it with?

Code below:

```
from numpy import pi, cos, sin, linspace, roll

from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

M = 5
N = M*10 + 1
r_base = 8
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, N)
r_x = linspace(0, 6*pi, N-1)
rmin = r_base - cos(r_x) - 1
rmax = r_base + sin(r_x) + 1

colors = ["FFFFCC", "#C7E9B4", "#7FCDBB", "#41B6C4", "#2C7FB8", "#253494", "#2C7FB8", "#41B6C4", "#7FCDBB", "#C7E9B4"] * M

p = figure(x_range=(-11, 11), y_range=(-11, 11))
r = p.annular_wedge(0, 0, rmin, rmax, theta[:-1], theta[1:],
                fill_color=colors, line_color="white")

session = push_session(curdoc())

ds = r.data_source

def update():
    rmin = roll(ds.data["inner_radius"], 1)
    rmax = roll(ds.data["outer_radius"], -1)
    ds.data.update(inner_radius=rmin, outer_radius=rmax)

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 30)

session.show(p) 

session.loop_until_closed()
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I start a Bokeh server in the directory with the Python file with

```
bokeh serve
```

and then open a new terminal and execute the Python file with

```
python animated.py
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know you had to open up a new terminal, silly me. Thank you very much Julian!